# Search with synonym letters for arabic language

Tags: plugins, hooks, search, actions

How can I have WordPress search different letters in Arabic?

For example, أ-ا-إ are the same letters but in different formats.

E.g. can I search WordPress for something like "world" > "?orld" (using REGEX or similar)?

Comment: Which search results do you want to affect - the main site search that visitors see? Someplace in wp-admin?